# Add "select tags" to ActiveRecord query with acts_as_taggable_on

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, acts-as-taggable-on

I have an ActiveRecord query like

```
Post.where("likes > 3")
```

and I would like have get the tags from acts_as_taggable_on for Post in my result. For example something like

```
Post.select("posts.*, tag_list").where("likes > 3")
```

Obviously this doesn't work, there is a whole lot of joins that need to happen to get the tags related to the Post from acts_as_taggable_on. Does acts_as_taggable_on provide any way to 'select' the tags?

I can access the tags with something like this:

```
Post.where("likes > 3").each do |p|
    puts p.to_json
    puts p.tag_list.to_json
end
```

but that results in a lot of queries, as there is a lot of Posts. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

I have found one way of making it work, but I was hoping for a nicer way, built into acts_as_taggable_on. Maybe there is a better way, but this seems to work:

```
Post.select("posts.*, tags.name as tag")
    .where("likes > 3")
    .joins(:taggings)
    .joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN tags on tags.id = taggings.tag_id")
```